# Complex insert query with insert into and where subquery in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, insert-into, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to figure out the best way to code this using `Query Builder` or `Eloquent`.

In it's simplest form it should prevent insert of a new *buy* request if an item already in `transactions` table. I haven't found any useful reference other than running a complete raw query.

```
INSERT INTO `transactions` 
    (`user_id`, `item_id`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
SELECT 
    1, 186808, 'bought', NOW(), NOW()
WHERE
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(
            CASE 
              WHEN `type` = 'bought' THEN 1
              WHEN `type` = 'sold' THEN -1
            END
        ) 
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE 
        (`item_id`, `user_id`) = (186808, 1)
    GROUP BY `item_id`
) = 0
```

Comment: I'm not really very familiar with Eloquent or QB, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is outside their scope and you have to use a raw query.

Comment: is this code review? what are you asking? what is your question you need help with?

Comment: I am unable to find any reference on how to do this. The only approach seems to just do a raw query. I am looking for a reference on how to draw up this query in Query Builder.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, you can use `DB::raw(<your_complex_query_here>)` to achieve this.

```
DB::raw("INSERT INTO `transactions` 
    (`user_id`, `item_id`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
SELECT 
    1, 186808, 'bought', NOW(), NOW()
WHERE
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(
            CASE 
              WHEN `type` = 'bought' THEN 1
              WHEN `type` = 'sold' THEN -1
            END
        ) 
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE 
        (`item_id`, `user_id`) = (186808, 1)
    GROUP BY `item_id`
) = 0");
```

For more, refer to Laravel docs here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#raw-expressions